# Javascript - ¿Cómo reemplazar éste script...?

Tags: javascript, html5

Estoy teniendo serios conflictos con una serie de **3 scripts** que al hacer click muestran y ocultan unos divs (toggle), y funcionaban muy bien hasta que agregué el último script (ver script-4), **el cual no puedo ni tocar**, pero me gustaría saber si los tres script a continuación pueden ser reemplazados de otra manera, cumpliendo la misma función de toggle, **y que no interfieran con las funciones del script-4**...

Alguna idea...?

Muchas gracias:

**CSS**

```
#info-1 {display:none}
#youtube-1 {display:none}
#ver-carrito {display:none}
```

//----------------

**Scripts 1, 2 y 3 en conflicto:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){$("#uno").click(function(t){t.preventDefault(),t.stopPropagation(),$("#info-1,.layer-2").toggle()}),$("#info-1,.layer-2").click(function(t){t.stopPropagation()}),$(".layer-2,body,.cerrar").click(function(){$("#info-1,.layer-2").hide()})});

//-----------------

$(document).ready(function(){$("#dos").click(function(t){t.preventDefault(),t.stopPropagation(),$("#youtube-1,.layer-2").toggle()}),$("#youtube-1,.layer-2").click(function(t){t.stopPropagation()}),$(".layer-2,body").click(function(){$("#youtube-1,.layer-2").hide()})});

//-----------------

$(document).ready(function(){$(".carrito").click(function(t){t.preventDefault(),t.stopPropagation(),$("#ver-carrito,.layer-2").toggle()}),$("#ver-carrito,.layer-2").click(function(t){t.stopPropagation()}),$("#close-ver-carrito,.layer-2,body").click(function(){$("#ver-carrito,.layer-2").hide()})});
```

//----------------

**Script 4 - No se puede tocar:**

```
let clicks = 0;
let clicksdos = 0;

const safeInt = (key) => {
  let value = parseInt(getValue(key));
  return (isNaN(value) || value < 0) ? 0 : value;
}

const loadClicks = () => {
  clicks = safeInt('clicks');
  clicksdos = safeInt('clicksdos');
}

const loadHTML = () => {
  return getValue('html', '');
}

const loadFromStorage = () => {
  let html = loadHTML();
  if(html !== '') {
    loadClicks();
  }
  displayClicks();
  document.querySelector(".contenido").innerHTML = html;
}

const displayClicks = () => {
    clicks = (clicks === NaN) ? 0 : clicks;
    clicksdos = (clicksdos === NaN) ? 0 : clicksdos;
    document.querySelector('#clicks').innerHTML = clicks;
    document.querySelector('#clicksdos').innerHTML = clicksdos; 
    let display = (clicks > 0) ? 'inline-block' : 'none';
      document.querySelector(".contenido").style.display = display;
}

const adjustClicks = (value) => {
  clicks +=value;
  clicksdos +=value;
  storeValue('clicks', clicks);
  storeValue('clicksdos', clicksdos);
  displayClicks();
}
const addClick = () => adjustClicks(1);
const removeClick = () => adjustClicks(-1);

const storeValue = (key, value) => (localStorage) ? localStorage.setItem(key, value) : '';
const getValue = (key, defaultValue) => (localStorage) ? localStorage.getItem(key) : defaultValue; 
const storeHTML = () => storeValue("html",document.getElementsByClassName("contenido")[0].innerHTML); 

const addToDerecha = (nodeId) => {
  let node = document.querySelector(`#${nodeId}`);
  document.querySelector('.contenido').appendChild(node.cloneNode(true));
  storeHTML();
  displaySuma();
};

document.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
  let target = event.target;
  if(target.matches('.comp-clone')) {  
    addClick();
    addToDerecha(event.target.dataset.clone);
  }

if(target.matches('.bbp')) {
    removeClick();
    getParent('.contenido', target).removeChild(target.parentNode);
    storeHTML();
    displaySuma();
  }
});

const getParent = (match, node) => (node.matches(match)) ? node : getParent(match, node.parentNode);
const displaySuma = () => document.getElementById("total").value = suma();
const suma = function () {
  return Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".contenido div .add-prod"))
  .reduce((a,v) => a + parseFloat(v.value), 0);
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  if(localStorage) {
  loadFromStorage();     
  }
  displaySuma();
});
```

Comment: Pienso que usas un navegador para probar tú código, si es así ¿Hay algún error en la consola?

Comment: Hola ftorres ... Nop. Ninguno. Sólo que al agregar los 3 script, el cuarto ya no funciona, por eso lo puse en el post, para ver qué puede interferir con él...

Comment: Recree lo que hiciste, tomé el mismo código y lo ejecuté, y funciona correctamente.

Comment: Por cierto, recuerda que `(NaN === NaN)` siempre es `false`

Comment: Gracias @ftorres. Entonces tengo problemas en otro script. Voy a investigar. Muchas gracias por tu tiempo. Un saludo.